# There is no "Convert MBR to GPT" option in EaseUs Partition Master

Tags: conversion, mbr, gpt, easeus-partition-manager

I want to convert my disk to GPT to install windows 10. I found this solution to convert it:

http://www.partition-tool.com/resource/GPT-disk-partition-manager/convert-mbr-disk-to-gpt-disk.htm

But in Easeus there is no convert option! What's wrong?

Comment: @Ramhound Please don't post answers as comments. If you have an answer, then please post it as an answer.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling  that was not an answer merely a you are using a bad tool and tutorial.

Comment: @linuxdev2013 The question is "why can't I convert MBR to GPT in EaseUs PM?". Ramhound posted a comment saying "you can't convert the system disk while using the system disk". That's an answer to the question as asked, not a request for clarification or suggestion for improvement of the question itself. Hence, it should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - I will just remove the comment then.  I appreciate the feedback.  I don't submit answers unless they are extremely high quality and I can't do that with any answer I could submit to this answer.

Comment: @Ramhound Go ahead and post it as an answer instead. I'm not familiar with the software, but it does sound to me like a valid answer; it just wasn't appropriate as a *comment*.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - Which is the reason I took your feedback into consideration and deleted my comment.

Comment: It's more a matter of the fact ANY mounted system disk/drive will not be "convert-able"  Irregardless of the tool used..  but that linked tutorial was also overall trash (especially for a new user)

Comment: @linuxdev2013 - Their offshore support chat is even worst then the tutorial :-)

Comment: Sadly that does NOT surprise me.

Answer (score 1):

Like Ramhound mentioned the drive /disk MUST be unmounted   to assume this is a windows install   grab any live installer (live as in  can actually use the system -- aka almost any modern linux installer or a Win rescue cd/dvd  if oyu have one handy )

Step 1)  BACKUP ALL IMPORTANT data ---confirm it was a valid backup (normally I boot it and check that it runs  for this purpose)

Step 2) load up the rescue cd/dvd  or live  installer  also very nice is  gparted iso  ([Gparted](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) )

Step 3) using  any of the above Follow either the DiskPART instructs from that Tutorial OR  the much more graphical and user friendly  Gparted iso  (also a great live tool for cross platform oh crap moments --keep a copy on usb myself)

3A) USING GPARTED select  ' Device' > >  `Create  Partition Table`  > >  from the drop-down select GPT (GUID) and then `Apply`

**WIN 7 USER SIDE NOTE:**

Some laptops / PCs and win 7 versions DO not like installing with boot  GPT+EFI this is nearly non existent issue on win 8  or xp  (for those that still use it )

Comment: Please don't use code blocks (4 spaces) because it requires a lot of unnecessary horizontal scrolling to read everything. Use a quote block instead if you must.

Comment: Thanks. Then The disk is not convertible just because a windows os is installed on it? Is GPT needed for win10?