# How can I convert my partition from GPT to MBR and make my system dual boot Kali and Windows?

Tags: windows-8.1, kali-linux, mbr, gpt, dualboot

I want someone to help me how to install Kali on my laptop and want to know how to convert a GPT partition to MBR.

I searched on YouTube but most of the popular tutorials didn’t work. Even after successfully installing it not booting in Kali rather than that its booting in Windows 8.1.

I contacted one laptop service center he said that its not possible to install it on Windows 8.1 you have to upgrade it to 10 and then he can install Kali on my laptop for 700 rupees which is very expensive amount for me. I tried to convince the service center that I am a student give some discount he turned me away.

I tried to install Kali more than 15 times but I failed. I think its my mistake because I don’t like reading stuffs. I decided to use it inside a VM (VMware)buy it hangs very much and cannot  use it efficiently.

```
Recently I tried to install it with Rufus.
```

- kali-linux-2020.2-installer-amd64 I selected as ISO image.
- file system was fat32.
- DD image I selected
- After making the pendrive bootable
- turned off secure boot
- turned on legacy boot
- restarted my system.
- selected graphical install
- clicked all the options.
- partitioning my disk
- first partition was root ext4
- second partition was home ext4
- third partition was swap
- Mount I selected as MBR
- Started installing software left it as it was.

Then it displayed the message that Kali has been successfully installed and message displayed to remove my USB flash drive and restart.

I did, but could not see the grub boot loader.

I want to mention that in Rufus I also tried use in all possible combination like MBR  and file system is NTFS.

My sys configuration

```
brand         : dell inspiron 5000 series
HD            : western digital
OS            : windows 8.1 original
BIOS  version : A02:
```

**Question 1**: I would be grateful if someone could guide me to install Kali.

I installed Kali Linux on my system but it didn’t boot in to it rather that it boot into Windows 8.1. So after installing I tried to used EasyBCD when I runs it it shows a message that boot mode it set to EFI by  Microsoft due to that full functionality is not accessible to it so I can’t make a way for Kali.

Then I decided to change the partition to MBR but failed.

I have one hard disk and a USB flash drive. I have made the USB flash drive bootable and but could not install Kali and make it dual boot with Windows 8.1. After searching like hell I found that I must change partition to MBR from GPT.

There was no free software available to do that.

Here is the software I have tried to convert my disk partition to MBR:

- EaseUS Partion
- MiniToolPartition
- MacroritPartition

I found [some links](https://superuser.com/questions/917237/there-is-no-convert-mbr-to-gpt-option-in-easeus-partition-master) but it doesn't assure that my Windows install will not be deleted and I could make dual boot.

**Question 2**: How can I convert my partition from GPT to MBR and make my system dual boot?

Comment: GPT  not required for dualboot.You can dual boot using MBR as well. MBR has limitations like 4 partition limit which makes dualbooting a little more complex !! So first decide MBR or GPT .Things not clear from question - Windows BIOS mode? Disk in GPT or MBR format? Want to install on vm-ware or dualboot ? What do you mean by this "Mount I selected as MBR" ?

Comment: Kali supports GPT.  I know you want to convert your disk to MBR, but if you have more than 4 partitions, that won't be possible.

Comment: I dont want to install kali on a virtual machine in windows .What I want to make it dual boot.

Comment: Windows 8 can boot from GPT. Why do you need to convert back to MBR?

Comment: Window 8 is bootable is want to make Kali bootable.So by converting my disk from GPT to MBR I want to try agian reinstall kali. And praying that that would work but I am not sure.

Comment: @DevParzival just enter UEFI setup and add Kali's bootloader and it'll solve the problem in most cases

Comment: @phuclv guide me if I am wrong rather than UEFI we have to turn on legacy boot so we can boot from pendrive and install OS.

Comment: if the pendrive doesn't boot in UEFI mode then you're creating it wrong. Anyway it's easy to convert from a BIOS installation to UEFI without reinstalling [Which commands to convert a Ubuntu BIOS install to EFI/UEFI without boot-repair on single boot hardware?](https://askubuntu.com/q/509423/253474). After that just copy bootx64.efi to the ESP. And if you don't know a lot of things then you should try other distros first. See [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/44425)

Comment: @phuclv I have windows system in that I am trying to istall kali and make it dual boot.

Comment: @phuclv the link which u have sent regarding why Kali is hard.I know Kali I use it inside virtual box by oracle but ya just want to dual boot .

Comment: @dev Hope you work well in kali Linux, Can you please help on https://superuser.com/questions/1599056/ralink-mt7601u-wi-fi-usb-adapter-failed-to-set-master-mode

Comment: @Nullpointer it was bit complected for me I have not explored that much in Kali so I could not answer hope you will get your answer <*j*>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is strongly advisable you backup your information. Even more so under the circumstances you describe.**

I found several sources mentioning that grub does not show up after a dual boot installation, and related, see below.
Some of them refer to Kali, and some do not; many (but not all) of the comments there should apply anyway, since [it is Debian-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_Linux).

As per your description, I am not certain what sequence you tried, and what is the current state of your system.
I guess it is set to UEFI boot.
Dual booting with Kali should work.
There seems to be no need to

1. Convert from GPT to MBR (it is advisable that you link the sources you mention)
2. Upgrade from Win 8.1 to Win 10, although it is strongly advisable.
   Most of the sources mention Win 10 anyway, so I would not be certain the upgrade is not needed.

The answer **can be fine tuned upon your feedback** on:

1. What you see in the UEFI boot menu (a description plus an image helps).
   Extra info as mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/419806/137608) helps.

The **possible solutions** show a significant spread.
I post a summary, while I wait for your feedback:

1. **The `bcdedit`way**.
   Run from within Windows `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path /EFI/Kali/grub64.efi` ([source](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?29106-Kali-Dual-Boot-problem-after-installation&p=54816#post54816)).
   This is alternative to the Ubuntu version [Fix Grub Not Showing For Windows 10 Linux Dual Boot](https://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/) `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`.
   Apparently both slash or backslash work.
   See also [How to Dual Boot Windows 7 and Linux using BCDEdit](https://www.iceflatline.com/2009/09/how-to-dual-boot-windows-7-and-linux-using-bcdedit/) and
   [Windows 7: How to use BCDEDIT to create a new entry for Linux?](https://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/326809-how-use-bcdedit-create-new-entry-linux.html)
2. [Reinstall GRUB](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?35808-Grub-is-not-showing-on-windows-10-computer&s=c365002f211c90700f87e0d970f01c8f&p=70333#post70333).
3. [Set the Kali partition to bootable](http://techsarjan.com/2017/09/solved-kali-linux-grub-error-problem-windows-10-dual-boot-problem.html#:%7E:text=You%20need%20to%20ON%20this,on%20startup%20in%20your%20system.&text=So%20the%20first%20solution%20of,problem%20again%20in%20your%20system.).
4. Last resort #1: Use [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html).
5. Last resort #2: [Install a triple boot with Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/426433/137608).

**Related links**

1. [Grub is not showing on windows 10 computer](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?35808-Grub-is-not-showing-on-windows-10-computer)
2. [Restore Dual Boot of Kali and Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1078501/restore-dual-boot-of-kali-and-windows-10)
3. [Solved -Kali Linux Grub Error Problem with Windows 10 dual boot Problem](http://techsarjan.com/2017/09/solved-kali-linux-grub-error-problem-windows-10-dual-boot-problem.html#:%7E:text=You%20need%20to%20ON%20this,on%20startup%20in%20your%20system.&text=So%20the%20first%20solution%20of,problem%20again%20in%20your%20system.)
4. [Kali 2.0 GRUB Problem Windows 10](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/forum/kali-2-0-grub-problem-windows-10-0165337/)
5. [Dual-boot boot menu does not show up after installing Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717904/dual-boot-boot-menu-does-not-show-up-after-installing-ubuntu-15-10-alongside-win)
6. [Installed Debian alongside Windows 10 but GRUB does not show](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/561095/installed-debian-alongside-windows-10-but-grub-does-not-show)
7. [How to Get Ubuntu to Boot Before Windows](https://www.lifewire.com/fix-uefi-bootloader-issues-when-dual-booting-2200655)
8. [How To Access UEFI Firmware Settings In Windows 10](https://itsfoss.com/access-uefi-settings-windows-10/)

Comment: can u tell me how can I do this `I think I have resolved the problem. I run from windows bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path /EFI/Kali/grub64.efi and now the grub shows the menu list `

Answer (score 1):

I remark that you do not need dual boot in order to run Kali Linux on Windows 10 WSL.
This will avoid the need to convert the disk and the possibility of loosing everything.

Kali Linux is available from the
[Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/kali-linux/9pkr34tncv07?activetab=pivot:overviewtab).

It is advisable to first update Windows 10 to version 2004 and to enable WSL2.
You will need to enable the Windows features of "Windows Subsystem for Linux"
and "Virtual Machine Platform", then install Kali from the Microsoft Store.

For details see the article
[How to install Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 on Windows 10](https://pureinfotech.com/install-windows-subsystem-linux-2-windows-10/).

I advise to take good backups before starting, up to taking a backup image of
the disk.
For taking an image backup of the system disk one product is
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html).
Make a
[bootable media](https://www.backup-utility.com/features/create-bootable-disc.html),
and test booting it to see that it can see both the hard disk and the
backup image, just in case you will want to restore the last working
version of Windows.

Comment: some people to whom I talked they said it is not possible to `dual boot` with `windows 8 and 8.1` and have to upgrade to `10` is it true? I don't want to switch from `windows 8.1` to `10`.Reason is `8.1` is very cute to and appealing to me as compare to windows 10.

Comment: As far as features go, there is no comparison between Windows 10 and 8.1. I seriously recommend, also for security reasons. Keep in mind my recommendation for backup.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see, you haven't installed Kali on your system, but instead you've made your USB drive bootable through Rufus.

Upon booting, click the <kbd>F2</kbd> key and you should enter the BIOS menu. From there choose boot options or something similar and select your USB. It should boot into Kali.

Choose “Try Now” or some similar option. If you want to dual boot, you can choose “Install Now” but I'd refrain from making Kali a permanent OS.

Comment: since its GPT partition windows would not let kali to boot through Grub boot loader.

Comment: I have tried to install kali many times but still grub boot loader is not  showing.

Comment: @DevParzival probably you didn't disable SecureBoot, because Windows doesn't prevent Grub from booting in anyway. It only overwrites the bootloader in MBR because there can be only one in that tiny sector. In UEFI all the bootloaders are stored as files in the ESP and Windows just copy it's bootloader there

Comment: @phuclv I did turn off sucure boot from Bios and then try to install kali.