# Ralink MT7601U Wi-Fi USB adapter failed to set master mode

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, kali-linux, chipset, packet-injection

I'm using virtualbox with installed latest `Kali linux` for Wifi related stuff for education purpose only where I using `MT7601U` chipset for same.

[fluxion](https://github.com/FluxionNetwork/fluxions) tool for Captive Portal in client end also tried to used`hostapd` but both are not working because of something issue in the driver or hardware limitation, I guess

Unable to set Master mode :

```
root@raspberrypi:~/# iwconfig wlan0 mode master
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.
```

Device information :

```
root@kali:~# iw list | grep "Supported interface modes" -A 8
Supported interface modes:
* managed
* monitor
Band 1:
Capabilities: 0x17e
HT20/HT40
SM Power Save disabled
RX Greenfield
RX HT20 SGI
```

Specs

```
[FLUXION Info]

[Interface (wlan0) Info]
Device: phy0
Driver: mt7601u
Chipset: Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U
Injection Test: Injection is working!
```

Does is this hardware supported monitor mode, packet injection ann along with AP mode ? Does Hardware supported all above futures ?

`RT5370` chipset supported Master mode ?

Does `iw list` command give information directly from hardware or It's depends on drivers ? For example, here I can see managed and monitor mode only, if I installed well/modified drivers then it's will see like managed, monitor, AP mode ?

I have read a lot of web pages with a lots of hints, but without success.

If you have any positive results on this issue, please let me know. Thanks in advance!